# Reading property from a function output

Tags: javascript

```
(function(){
  function sayHello(){
    var name = "Hi John";
    return
    {
      fullName: name
    }
  } 

  console.log(sayHello().fullName);
})();
```

The console will output

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullName' of undefined

I read this question from an interview exercise book,and I cannot understand the reason behind this, anyone could help me?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is automatic semicolon insertion after `return` statement.

You can't place code on a new line after return statement because javascript will automatically place `;` on the same line with return statement and the rest of the code is ignored.

```js
(function(){
  function sayHello() {
    var name = "Hi John";
    return { fullName: name };
  }

  console.log(sayHello().fullName);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of *A*utomatic *S*emicolon *I*nsertion the parser will read your code as:

```
return  ; // <---
{
  fullName: name
}
```

So it returns actually nothing, which is `undefined` in javascript.

By the way: The following object literal also gets invalid as it is not an expression anymore but a statement (a *block statement*) and then the key-value-pair doesn't make sense.